# javascript Close button not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to close my modal, but it is not closing. If I click on button to close modal, the whole page reloads. How can I fix this.

Here my code:-

```
  <button id="myBtn2">Read more</button>
  <span class="more"></span>
```

Here model:-

```
 <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img src="images/abcd.jpeg" style="width:300px;margin:5px; padding-bottom: 10px;border-radius: 20px;" alt="Web Design Trends" />
  <img src="images/aaa.jpeg" style="width:300px;margin:5px;padding-bottom: 10px;border-radius: 20px;" alt="Web Design Trends" />
  <img src="images/bbb.jpeg" style="width:300px;margin:5px;padding-bottom: 10px;border-radius: 20px;" alt="Web Design Trends" />
  <img src="images/ccc.jpeg" style="width:300px;margin:5px;padding-bottom: 10px;border-radius: 20px;" alt="Web Design Trends" />
  </div>

  </div>
```

Here my script:-

```
<script>
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  }
  span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  }
  </script>
```

Plese help me thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "close reload the whole page" ?

Comment: Try to console the value of your `span` variable. To check if the selector is correct.

Comment: to close the open model @FlyingGambit

Comment: Maybe there is another element with class `close`?

Comment: yes, i have another close for another model @SebastianKaczmarek

Comment: Your code works fine for me so there must be something else. Check if you haven't added class `close` to other element which is higher in DOM and by `var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];` you are reffering to completely another button. Check also if there isn't some other JS script which causes page reload on `close` click

Comment: yes I have another model and close used in that model @SebastianKaczmarek

Comment: And does it work with the another modal?

Comment: no, @SebastianKaczmarek

Comment: Okay so try doing this and let me know if it works. Change `class` to `id`: `<span id="closeMyModal2">&times;</span>` and then in your JS: `var span = document.getElementById("closeMyModal2");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running this ..

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.close{
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal{
     max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn2">Read more</button>
<span class="more"></span>


<div id="myModal2" class="modal" style="display:none;">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close"><b>&times;</b></span>
    <img src="images/abcd.jpeg" style="width:300px;margin:5px; padding-bottom: 10px;border-radius: 20px;" alt="Web Design Trends" />
    <img src="images/aaa.jpeg" style="width:300px;margin:5px;padding-bottom: 10px;border-radius: 20px;" alt="Web Design Trends" />
    <img src="images/bbb.jpeg" style="width:300px;margin:5px;padding-bottom: 10px;border-radius: 20px;" alt="Web Design Trends" />
    <img src="images/ccc.jpeg" style="width:300px;margin:5px;padding-bottom: 10px;border-radius: 20px;" alt="Web Design Trends" />
  </div>
</div>
```